# Redefinition of class function error C++

Tags: c++, function, class, virtual

I have my base class Gate, whilst the derived class is AND (XOR etc.).  The virtual function I have in my base class is for determining an output, but when I prototype it in AND.h and try and implement it with AND.cpp I get the redefinition error on compile.  I am sure I have included everything properly.

Gate header

```
#ifndef GATE_H
#define GATE_H

class Gate{
    public:
        // various functions etc.

        virtual bool output();   // **PROBLEM FUNCTION**

};

#endif
```

Gate source

```
#include "Gate.h"

//*various function declarations but not virtual declaration*
```

Derived class "AND"

```
#ifndef AND_H_INCLUDED
#define AND_H_INCLUDED

class AND: public Gate{
public:
    bool output(bool A, bool B){}
};
#endif // AND_H_INCLUDED
```

and where my IDE puts my error occuring in the AND.h file

```
#include "AND.h"

bool AND::output(bool A, bool B){
    if (A && B == true){
        Out = true;
    } else {
        Out = false;
    }

    return Out;
}
```

Out in this case is an inherited variable.

Comment: Your `AND` header should be including the one it needs in order to compile.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, you can't declare a function with no arguments and then redefine it with arguments.

Comment: @Mauren, In this case, it will be shadowed.

Comment: To be honest, I'd make that `output` function just `return Out = A && B;`.

Comment: @chris true, thanks for pointing out. However it doesn't seem to be what the OP wants anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're providing two definitions of `AND::output`. One in the header, which is empty, and another in the implementation file, which is not empty. Looks like your header should have:

```
bool output(bool A, bool B);
```

Note that you will not be able to use these `output` functions polymorphically because they do not have the same arguments as the declaration in `Gate`.

Comment: My header DOES have what you specified in its public: terms.  I thought that virtual functions got passed to the derived classes which were then capable of defining them?

Comment: @user3344556, Only if the signature matches (well, roughly because the return type needs to as well).

Comment: @user3344556 No it doesn't. Check again. And what Chris said.

Comment: Thanks, I see now.  AND.h still has one remaining error though "expected class name before '{' token

Comment: @user3344556 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21976008/redefinition-of-class-function-error-c#comment33300911_21976008

Comment: @chris Oh yeah, good spot. `AND.h` needs to `#include "Gate.h"`.

Comment: @user3344556, Since you haven't included the file that has `Gate`, it's just a random piece of text as far as the compiler knows at that point.

Answer (score 3):

You are defining method `AND::output` in the `AND` class definition here:

```
bool output(bool A, bool B){} // this is a definition
```

and you are re-defining it here:

```
bool AND::output(bool A, bool B){

  if (A && B == true){
  ....
```

You can fix this by changing the former to a declaration:

```
bool output(bool A, bool B);
```

Answer (score 1):

As it was already said you defined function output twice: in the header and in the cpp module. Also this function is not virtual because its number and types of parameters do not coinside with the declaration of the virtual function with the same name in the base class.

I would like to append that the function could be defined much simpler

```
bool AND::output(bool A, bool B)
{
   return ( Out = A && B );
}
```